# How to calculate response time (excluding latency) from given statistics

Tags: performance, networking, performance-testing, fiddler

I am trying to calculate response time of individual requests. I am using Fiddler tool for monitoring traffic. It provides following statistics:

```
ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    07:37:07.616
ClientBeginRequest: 07:37:12.993
GotRequestHeaders:  07:37:12.993
ClientDoneRequest:  07:37:12.993
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    07:37:07.622
FiddlerBeginRequest:07:37:12.993
ServerGotRequest:   07:37:12.993
ServerBeginResponse:07:37:12.995
GotResponseHeaders: 07:37:12.995
ServerDoneResponse: 07:37:13.003
ClientBeginResponse:07:37:13.003
ClientDoneResponse: 07:37:13.003
Overall Elapsed:    00:00:00.0099623
```

I am not sure which parameters are important here in order to calculate response time (excluding network latency etc). How should I do it and which formula should be used for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latency is basically time taken for response to download because of network.
Response time is TTLB (time to last byte).

So in order to get response time (without delay).. I used following formula..

= TTLB - (TTFB - TTLB)

```
Where TTLB starts from ClientDoneRequest and ends at ClientDoneResponse =
ClientDoneRequest:  07:37:12.993
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    07:37:07.622
FiddlerBeginRequest:07:37:12.993
ServerGotRequest:   07:37:12.993
ServerBeginResponse:07:37:12.995
GotResponseHeaders: 07:37:12.995
ServerDoneResponse: 07:37:13.003
ClientBeginResponse:07:37:13.003
ClientDoneResponse: 07:37:13.003
```

and

```
TTFB starts from ClientDoneRequest and ends at ClientBeginResponse =
ClientDoneRequest:  07:37:12.993
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    07:37:07.622
FiddlerBeginRequest:07:37:12.993
ServerGotRequest:   07:37:12.993
ServerBeginResponse:07:37:12.995
GotResponseHeaders: 07:37:12.995
ServerDoneResponse: 07:37:13.003
ClientBeginResponse:07:37:13.003
```